# Why the set of sequence s.t. $x_{n+2}=ax_{n+1}+bx_n$ has dimension $2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, vector-spaces

Why the vector space $V$ of real sequence s.t. $x_{n+2}=ax_{n+1}+bx_n$ has dimension $2$ ? (I guess that we suppose that $a^2+4b>0$, otherwise is not really well defined.

I proved that if $x_n=r^n$ then $(x_n)\in V\iff r^2-ar-b=0$
then if $r_1,r_2$ are roots of the previous polynomial, then $$Span\{r_1,r_2\}\subset V.$$
This prove that $\dim V\geq 2$. But how can I prove that $\dim V=2$ ?

Answer (score 4):

I have no idea about why you think that we should have $a^2+4b>0$.

Anyway, consider the sequences$$1,0,b,a b,b a^2+b^2,b a^3+2 b^2 a,\ldots\tag1$$and$$0,1,a,a^2+b,a^3+2 b a,a^4+3 b a^2+b^2,\ldots\tag2$$Each sequnce $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that $(\forall n\in\mathbb N):x_{n+2}=ax_{n+1}+bx_n$ can be written in one and only one way as a linear combination of $(1)$ and $(2)$. Therefore, the space of all those sequence is $2$-dimensional.

Comment: Because I'm on $V$ a subspace of $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ as a $\mathbb R$ vector space. So, if $a^2+4b<0$ I don't have solution of $r^2-ar-b=0$. Does it make sense ore not really ? For your argument, your sequence (1) and (2) looks a bit complicated, no ? And how can I prove that it can be written in only one way as a linear combinaison of them ?

Comment: No, that makes no sense at all. Take $a=0$ and $b=-1$. Then $a^2+4b<0$ and the sequence$$0,1,0,-1,0,1,0,-1,\ldots$$satisfies the condition that you mentioned. Don't you agree?

Comment: ok, but foe example, if $r^2=b$ with $b<0$, then there are no real sequence right ?

Comment: What is that $r$? Are you assuming that your sequence must be a geometrical sequence?

Comment: Let $x_n=r^n$. Then, $r^{n+2}=ar^{n+1}+br^n$, and thus take $a=0$ and $b=-1$. So we have $r^2=b$. Such a sequence can not exist in $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$, right ?

Comment: Right, although totally irrelevant for this problem. Why are you obsessed with geometric sequences?

Comment: But you took $a=0$ and $b=-1$ in a previous example. So I take a case where the discriminant is negative to have no solution (that's why I took $a^4+4b>0$)

Comment: The sequence of my previous example was **not** a geometric sequence. Again, why do you even care about them?

Comment: Ok, so suppose we are in a case where $r^2-ar-b\neq 0$, i.e. if that equation has no real solution ? What happen ? What will be the sequences ?

Comment: What is that $r$?

Comment: ?? I'm trying to find seqences s.t. $x_{n+2}=\alpha x_{n+1}+\beta x_n$. So I set $x_n=r^n$ and then get $$r^2-\alpha r-\beta =0$$ So if there are solution, then such sequences are of the form $\lambda r_1^n+\mu r_2^n$. Now, if $r^2-\alpha r-\beta =0$ has no solution, how can I find the sequences that satisfy $x_{n+2}=\alpha x_{x+1}+\beta x_n$ ?

Comment: What what makes you think that your sequence will be of the form $(r^n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$?

Comment: I don't whant form of $r^n$, I want linear combinaison of $sequence of the form $r^n$. Why ? Because it's the hint given by my exercise

Comment: I have nothing to do with the hints that someone else gave you.

Answer (score 1):

The dimension is the length of the recurrence.  Because you have terms ranging from $x_n$ to $x_{n+2}$ you need two starting values to define the sequence, say $x_0$ and $x_1$.  You can then compute all the subsequent terms. That gives rise to two independent solutions, which is the dimension $2$ you are asking about.  If your recurrence went up to $x_{n+3}$ you would need three starting values and get a three dimensional solution space.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to be sure that the set of sequences $x=\{x_i\}$ that satisfy a recurrence relation of the form $x_{n+2}=ax_{n+1}+bx_n$ (for fixed $a$ and $b$) really is a vector space. This is true because if $\{\alpha_i\}$ and $\{\beta_i\}$ satisfy the recurrence relation then so do $\{\lambda\alpha_i\}$ and $\{\alpha_i+\beta_i\}$. But this is only true because the recurrence relation is linear - it would not hold for the solutions of $x_{n+2}=x_{n+1}^2+x_n$ for example.

One way to determine the dimension of this vector space is to find a basis for it. A natural basis to try is the two solutions

$\alpha = \{1,0,b,ab,a^2b+b^2,\dots\} \\
\beta = \{0,1,a,a^2+b, a^3+2ab, \dots\}$

$\alpha$ and $\beta$ are linearly independent since one is not a multiple of the other. And they span the set of solutions because if we have any solution $x=\{x_i\}$ then

$x = x_0\alpha + x_1\beta = \{x_0, x_1, ax_1+bx_0, a^2x_1+abx_0+bx_1, \dots \}$

If $r_1$ and $r_2$ are the roots of $r^2-ar-b=0$ then as long as $r_1 \ne r_2$ we also have a basis

$\gamma = \{1,r_1, r_2^2, r_1^3,\dots\} \\
\delta = \{1,r_2, r_2^2, r_2^3, \dots\}$

Again, $\gamma$ and $\delta$ are linearly independent and for any solution $x=\{x_i\}$ we have

$x = k_1\gamma + k_2\delta \\
k_1=\frac{r_2x_0-x_1}{r_2-r_1}\\
k_2=\frac{x_1-r_1x_0}{r_2-r_1}$

As long as $a,b,x_0,x_1$ are real then all terms in $x$ will be real, even if $r_1,r_2,k_1,k_2$ are complex.